# Can functions be classed as data structures?

Tags: python

I am doing my write-up for a school project, and we have to write about the data structures we used. I was wondering whether or not functions would come under the category of data structures.

Comment: Generally no.  You would use functions to manipulate data structures, and you might even hold first-class functions in data structures.  But, in general, a data structure is a structure that holds data.

Comment: This question, if worked out to include your *own* research, could be on-topic for Programmers. As worded it is too broad for Stack Overflow however.

Comment: There is no ready made answer to that. It depends pretty much on what you are willing to call data-structure.  Would you consider that a lone integer variable is a data structure? What about a lone integer constant? What about a composite of variables and constants?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I now understand that my question was vague and apologize for it being unspecific.